# Clone selected schemas from postgres database to new server

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have a postgres database with +150 almost identical shemas that contains + 1 tb data. We are about to full clone the database, BUT with only with 3 selected schemas (admin, postgres, master) including their data, functions, ect to another database on another server.

How do I do this the most easy way, if a full pg_dump including all the data from all the irrelevant schemas is not an option?

Comment: You can dump just selected schemas with `pg_dump` using the `--schema` option

Comment: Thanks. I have never tried that. If I do that, will the rest of the database, that is, all the non shemas also be there? Example: I have installed the pg_agent with rules, will it be in the pg_dump too when I only select some shemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some useful informations if you run `pg_dump --help` .

```
  -n, --schema=SCHEMA          dump the named schema(s) only
  -N, --exclude-schema=SCHEMA  do NOT dump the named schema(s)
```

And the option above would be what you want.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Example it is with the 3 shemas : pg_dump -n 'admin', -n  'postgres', -n  'master' mydb > db.sql